# Как перевести строку "1d 2h 3m 4s" в миллисекунды?

Tags: java, время

Как перевести строку в миллисекунды?

Например строчка `1s` => 1000ms, а `1m` => 60000ms, а если `5s 1m` или `1m 5s` => 65000ms

Думаю надо переводить строку в массив, а потом проходиться по значениям и записывать в переменную миллисекунды, но не знаю как сделать :(

Comment: Распарсить строку, домножить каждое значение на соответствеющее количество милисекунд, сложить.

Answer (score 5):

Можно воспользоваться методом `Duration.parse()`, класса `java.time.Duration`, только нужно предварительно подготовить строку, убрав пробелы, перегнав всё в верхний регистр и поставив символ `T` после числа дней:

```java
String str = "1d 2h 3m 4s";

String durationStr = "P" + str
    .replace("d ", "dt")
    .replace(" ", "").toUpperCase();

// durationStr: P1DT2H3M4S

Duration duration = Duration.parse(durationStr);
System.out.println(duration.toMillis());

// результат: 93784000
```

Как уже сказали в комментариях - да, этот вариант не подразумевает другой порядок. Чтобы можно было менять порядок, можно доработать решение, например, так:

```java
String str = "1d 2h 4s 3m";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)([dhms])");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);

HashMap<String, Long> map = new HashMap<>();
while(matcher.find()) {
    map.put(
        matcher.group(2),
        Long.parseLong(matcher.group(1)) + map.getOrDefault(matcher.group(2), 0L)
    );
}

String durationStr = "pdthms".chars()
    .mapToObj(c -> "" + ((char) c))
    .map(c -> "" + (map.containsKey(c) ? map.get(c) : "") + c)
    .map(String::toUpperCase)
    .collect(Collectors.joining());

Duration duration = Duration.parse(durationStr);
System.out.println(duration.toMillis());
```

Comment: Если поменять порядок, работать не будет (при вашей текущей реализации).

Comment: Минимум в ~35 раз медленнее (на моей машине), и кода ненамного меньше, чем в моём ответе, а сложность кода для понимания новичкам больше. Я бы не советовал использовать примудрости там, где в них нет необходимости :)

Comment: @PeterSamokhin ~35 - откуда такое число? :)

Comment: На самом деле, даже в 60. Тестировал с помощью обычного JUnit, ваш пример в лучшем случае выдает 58-60 мс, мой — не больше 2 мс :)

Comment: ок, с помощью JMH ещё можете измерить?

Comment: Не совсем сподручно, если честно, можно позже будет сделать. Вот JUnit: https://imgur.com/a/SrBQH

Answer (score 2):

Для вашего формата строки метод ниже будет универсальным. Постарайтесь не глупо скопировать, а ещё лучше — использовать другой способ, он тут явно не один.

```
/**
 * @param  str Исходная строка в формате `1d 2h 3m 4s`.
 * @return     Подсчитанное количество миллисекунд.
 */
private long calculateMillisecondsCount(String str) {
    String[] words = str.split(" ");

    long totalMillisecondsCount = 0;

    for (String word : words) {
        String literal = word.substring(word.length() - 1);
        TimeUnit unit;
        long count;

        switch (literal) {
            case "d": {
                unit = TimeUnit.DAYS;
                break;
            }
            case "h": {
                unit = TimeUnit.HOURS;
                break;
            }
            case "m": {
                unit = TimeUnit.MINUTES;
                break;
            }
            case "s": {
                unit = TimeUnit.SECONDS;
                break;
            }
            default:
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }

        count = Integer.parseInt(word.substring(0, word.indexOf(literal)));

        totalMillisecondsCount += TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(count, unit);
    }

    return totalMillisecondsCount;
}
```